# How to get math scaling right with fontspec/unicode-math

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize, unicode-math, scaling

I've tried to get the math scaling right in a number of different ways, but have failed.  What is the proper syntax here? The posting [unicode math font smaller than the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412305/unicode-math-font-smaller-than-the-text) seems relevant, but that didn't work.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Baskervaldx-Reg}[Scale=0.2]
\setmathfont{Baskervaldx-Reg}[Scale=0.2]

\begin{document}
\lipsum 

$x=y$ 

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Baskervaldx-Reg is not a math font. And what is the sense of a scale factor of 0.2?

Comment: you can only use fonts that have an OpenType MATH table with `unicode-math`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah, thanks.  The scale factor of 0.2 was to make the problem visible in the example output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle aha, it works with STIX2Math.  Thanks.  I'll accept your comment if you post it as an answer.

Comment: See also [Which OpenType Math fonts are available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use fonts that have an OpenType MATH table with `unicode-math`